Parner event grid topic - adding a .NET Core server app as a subscriber
I have created a MS Graph subscription that sends notifications to my event grid in azure whenever there are group changes.
I have an Azure function that is subscribed to this event topic and is called whenever a new message from Graph arrives.
But now I need to extend this prototype to demonstrate how to notify an ASP.NET Core MVC application that runs behind our corporate firewall.
I found this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/subscribe-to-partner-events#subscribe-to-events
In that section, it says the following:

First, create an event handler that will handle events from the
partner. For example, create an event hub, Service Bus queue or topic,
or an Azure function. Then, create an event subscription for the
partner topic using the event handler you created.

I'm not sure which option - event hub or service bug queue would be a better fit for my use case.  I don't want to have to "pull".  But I want events to be pushed to my .NET Core app / API.
The other consideration is cost. This will be our first foray into this type of an architecture so I don't want to suggest something that is going to be very expensive.
Can someone either point me in the right direction / help me compare some of the pros / cons / feasibility of the options mentioned in the doc? Essentially, the question is, what's the best way to have changes in Entra trigger functionality on prem?
Please and thanks

Please share the code which you tried. Are you getting any error ?

@Harshitha There is no code to share.  I mean, I've created an MS Graph subscription.  it created a partner topic in my azure grid.  and when I change groups in Entra, the subscription successfully sends notifications to my partner topic.  That in turn triggers my AZ function.  But my question is now I need to extend the prototype and I want to notify a .net application.
